# INSERT with UNION ALL returns only the first select result - HIVE Beeline

Tags: sql, hive, hql, beeline

I want to do a query that inserts the result of table1 with table2 union's result. But when I try on beeline:

```
insert into table table3
select * from (
    select * from table1 t1 
    where 
        h_time > '2019-05-01 00:00:00' 
        and t1.id in (select id from table4)
    union all
    select * from table2 t2 
    where 
        h_time > '2019-05-01 00:00:00' 
        and t2.id not in (select id from table4)
);
```

**Consider that the both tables 1 and 2 have the same column numbers and datatypes have already fixed previously.**

The result in table3 is only the rows of table1. And when I change the position of table 1 and 2, I get only the rows of table2. 
Anyone have a guess what's happening?

Tks in advance!

Comment: Some questions: Why HQL tagged? Your is a SQL query. Are you sure the structure about your tables (table1 and table2) are the same (the same number of fields)?

Comment: Try using aliases for the queries  select c.* from (
    select a.* from table1 a where a.h_time > '2019-05-01 00:00:00'
    union all
    select b.* from table2 b where b.h_time > '2019-05-01 00:00:00'
) c ;

Comment: Sorry about the delay to reply you guys... I've tried your suggestion, but none of these worked for me... Futhermore, I will bring an update to this question, because the query has a subselect in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

it may be problem with table too, it may not show the actual count sometimes, use select * from tablename. If the count is as expected the run Analyze statement it'll re-compute and repair the statistics

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks!